# How to convert audio file to mp3 in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using **[flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound): ^9.2.13** package to record audio in my flutter app and it's in File format : **File: '/Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D8D77AE7-EE9B-4244-8707-98062B1F2FE1/data/Containers/Data/Application/B69AF519-A77A-4C5C-8D40-459003905B5F/tmp/audio'** it doesn't have extension, and I have to send it to sever but server only accepts `.mp3` file, how do I convert it and send it to server??

```
class PostComplainsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PostComplainsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PostComplainsPage> createState() => _PostComplainsPageState();
}

class _PostComplainsPageState extends State<PostComplainsPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    initRecorder();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    recorder.closeRecorder();
    super.dispose();
  }

  bool _isChecked = false;
  bool visibleText = true;
  late int grievanceId;
  String? imageOne, title, description, name, email, phone;
  File? audioFile;
  final grievanceType = TextEditingController();
  final wardno = TextEditingController();
  final isprivate = TextEditingController();
  final recorder =
      FlutterSoundRecorder(); //? this is for recording audio using flutter sound package

  Future record() async {
    //todo this is for start recording audio
    await recorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'audio');
  }

  Future stop() async {
    //todo this is for stop recording audio
    final filePath = await recorder.stopRecorder();
    final fileAudio = File(filePath!);
    audioFile = fileAudio;
    print('Recorded file path : $audioFile');
  }

  Future initRecorder() async {
    final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      context.showSnackbarError(message: 'Permission required');
    }
    await recorder.openRecorder();
    recorder.setSubscriptionDuration(const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => getIt<PostGrievanceCubit>(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: const kAppBar(title: 'नयाँ गुनासो'),
        ),
        body: BlocListener<PostGrievanceCubit, PostGrievanceState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            state.maybeWhen(
              orElse: () => null,
              success: (_) {
                context.showSnackbarSuccess(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                  message: 'Gunaso has been posted',
                );
                context.router.replace(
                  const BottomNavigationRoute(),
                );
              },
              loading: () {
                const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.pink,
                  ),
                );
              },
              error: (message) {
                context.showSnackbarError(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                  message: 'Failed, Please Try Again',
                );
              },
              noInternet: () => context.showSnackbarError(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                message: 'No Internet Connection',
              ),
            );
          },
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Containers(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  height: 30,
                  width: size.width,
                  child: const Texts(
                    texts: 'गुनसोकर्ताको जानकारी',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 15,
                ),
                Containers(
                  height: 30,
                  width: size.width,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Checkbox(
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(
                            () {
                              _isChecked = value!;
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        activeColor: AppColor.btnColor,
                        value: _isChecked,
                      ),
                      const Texts(
                        texts: 'गुनसोकर्ताको नाम गोप्य राख्नुहोस',
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                    imageOne != null
                        ? Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              child: Image.file(
                                File(imageOne!),
                                width: size.width,
                                height: 220,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    Visibility(
                      visible: true,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Containers(
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                radius: 45,
                                child: const Center(
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.image,
                                    size: 45,
                                    color: AppColor.btnColor,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onTap: () {
                                setState(
                                  () {
                                    visibleText = !visibleText;
                                  },
                                );
                                showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return Container(
                                      height: 120.9,
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                          children: [
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              height: 10.0,
                                            ),
                                            GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () async {
                                                final path = (await ImagePicker()
                                                        .pickImage(
                                                            source: ImageSource
                                                                .camera))
                                                    ?.path;
                                                if (path != null) {
                                                  imageOne = path;
                                                  if (mounted) {
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 40,
                                                width: size.width / 1.5,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          20.0),
                                                ),
                                                child: Row(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .center,
                                                    children: [
                                                      const Text(
                                                        'Camera',
                                                      ),
                                                      const SizedBox(
                                                        width: 5.0,
                                                      ),
                                                      const Icon(Icons.camera)
                                                    ]),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () async {
                                                final path = (await ImagePicker()
                                                        .pickImage(
                                                            source: ImageSource
                                                                .gallery))
                                                    ?.path;
                                                if (path != null) {
                                                  imageOne = path;
                                                  if (mounted) {
                                                    setState(() {});
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              },
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 40,
                                                width: size.width / 1.5,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                      BorderRadius.circular(
                                                          20.0),
                                                ),
                                                child: Row(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                  children: [
                                                    const Text(
                                                      'Gallery',
                                                    ),
                                                    const SizedBox(
                                                      width: 5.0,
                                                    ),
                                                    const Icon(
                                                      Icons.image,
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    )
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            const SizedBox(
                                              height: 10.0,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 10,
                            ),
                            const Texts(
                              texts: 'इमेज',
                              fontSize: 22,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 5.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    StreamBuilder<RecordingDisposition>(
                      stream: recorder.onProgress,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        final duration = snapshot.hasData
                            ? snapshot.data!.duration
                            : Duration.zero;
                        String twoDigits(int n) => n.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
                        final twoDigitsMinutes =
                            twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
                        final twoDigitsSeconds =
                            twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
                        return Texts(
                          texts: '$twoDigitsMinutes : $twoDigitsSeconds',
                          fontSize: 38,
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                    Containers(
                      onTap: () async {
                        if (recorder.isRecording) {
                          await stop();
                          setState(() {});
                        } else {
                          await record();
                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      },
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                        radius: 45,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                            recorder.isRecording
                                ? Icons.stop
                                : Icons.mic_none_rounded,
                            size: 48,
                            color: AppColor.btnColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    const Texts(
                      texts: 'अडियो',
                      fontSize: 22,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),
                BlocBuilder<PostGrievanceCubit, PostGrievanceState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                      child: CustomButton(
                        title: 'Submit',
                        loading: state.maybeWhen(
                          orElse: () => false,
                          loading: () => true,
                        ),
                        isDisabled: false,
                        onPressed: () async {
                          context.read<PostGrievanceCubit>().postGrievance(
                              title: title.toString(),
                              image: imageOne == null ? null : File(imageOne!),
                              audio: audioFile == null ? null : audioFile,
                              description: description.toString(),
                              wardno: int.parse(wardno.text),
                              name: name.toString(),
                              email: email.toString(),
                              phoneno: phone.toString(),
                              isprivate: _isChecked == false ? 0 : 1,
                              type: grievanceId);
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 35,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: read [startRecorder](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_sound/latest/recorder/FlutterSoundRecorder/startRecorder.html) docs - it has `codec` parameter, just use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the package record_mp3: https://pub.dev/packages/record_mp3/example

As it would record the file in Mp3 format and then you can send this file as Mp3 to the server